# iomanip, fixed and showpoint both "unable to resolve identifier"

Tags: c++, fixed, iomanip

I have tried to search for this issue and I just cannot find a solution. I am obviously new, and this is probably something simple. "fixed" and "showpoint" both come up with "unable to resolve identifier"

EDITED: I switched over from my laptop to my desktop, and now it doesn't give me that error anymore, I am guessing it's an issue with the compiler???

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

//Declaring global constants
    const double LOW = 0.10, MEDIUM = 0.15, HIGH = 0.20;
    const char *EARNED = "Commission:";

int main() {

    double commission = 0.0, salesAmount = 0.0;

    cout << "Enter your total sales amount: ";

    cin >> salesAmount;

    if ((salesAmount > 0)&&(salesAmount <= 5000)) 
    {    
        commission = salesAmount*LOW;
    }
    else if((salesAmount > 5000)&&(salesAmount <= 25000)) 
    {
        commission = salesAmount*MEDIUM;
    }
    else if(salesAmount > 25000) 
    { 
        commission = salesAmount*HIGH;
    }
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Sales:" << setw(10) << "$" << setw(10) << salesAmount << endl;
    cout << EARNED << setw(5) << "$" << setw(10) << commission;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `std::fixed and `std::showpoint` are defined in the header `<ios>`.

Comment: Also, this doesn't address the question, but you don't need all those parentheses in `if` statements.`if(salesAmount > 0 && salesAmount <= 5000)` works just fine. And note that, having just tested that `salesAmount <= 5000`, that `else if (salesAmount > 5000 && salesAmount <= 25000)` doesn't need the first test. You already know that if the code got there, `salesAmount` was greater than 5000, because the first `if` tested that. But you should probably test that `salesAmount` isn't less than 0 early on. Similarly, `else if (salesAmount > 25000)` should just be a plain `else`.

Comment: I really really really appreciate your help! I did what you told me to do, and the only thing that I am having trouble with is the last "else if". If I change it to "else" (which I tried doing before), it gives me unexpected token errors on everything after it

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
#include <ios>
```

That's where these operations are defined